# name and id for a select_tag in rails search_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How do I put name and id on a select_tag? I tried this way but i only got syntax error,

```
 <%= select_tag :product_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.order(:name), :id, :name, params[:product_modules][:product_id]), id: "product_modules[product_id]", { include_blank: true } %>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to display both name and id?

Comment: What syntax error do you got?

Comment: @Santosh. I want the name="product_modules[product_id]" (because of params) and the id="product_modules" (heritage of a ajax request);

Comment: @Pavan, ActionView::Template::Error (/home/lucas/Projects/operacao/src/app/views/organizations/index.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC
...id]", { include_blank: true } );@output_buffer.safe_concat('

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select_tag "product_modules[product_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Product.order(:name), :id, :name)
```